how to proof on coq double negation of p is logical equivalent to p
how to proof on coq double negation of p is logical equivalent to p?
¬(¬ p )->p
i found actually a way but this not seemed like the purest form. Can someone help?
Theorem double_neg : forall P : Prop, ~~P -> P.
Proof.
  intros P H.
  unfold not in H.
  pose proof (classic P) as HP_or_notP.
  destruct HP_or_notP as [HP | HnotP].
  - exact HP.
  - exfalso.
    apply H.
    exact HnotP.
Qed.

this is what i found but not seemed like the purest form.

Just to clarify: you want someone to make the proof cleaner?

To be also on the same board, are you aware that this theorem is not provable in vanilla Coq and requires an axiom (here, classic)?

sorry yes I know @Pierre-MariePédrot i added import classical code at first. I am begginer, trying to learn.

I take it you are using Coq.Logic.Classical from the StdLib, otherwise the code does not compile.
From Coq Require Import Classical.

(* The most direct I could make it with basic constructs: *)
Theorem double_neg : forall P : Prop,
  ~ ~ P -> P.
Proof.
  intros P HnnP.
  (* There is no need to 'pose' proof here,
     basic case analysis can be done
     with 'destruct' directly: *)
  destruct (classic P) as [HP|HnP].
  - exact HP.
  - (* There is no need for 'exfalso' here,
       directly destructing 'False' works: *)
    destruct (HnnP HnP).
Qed.

(* Notice that the built-in 'tauto' tactic also proves it, but
   be aware that this is only because we have imported Classical,
   otherwise 'tauto' is for intuitionistic tautologies only
   (though I have not found this behaviour documented anywhere): *)
Theorem double_neg' : forall P : Prop,
  ~ ~ P -> P.
Proof. tauto. Qed.

